How to extract colors from a palette in Material 3
With Material 2 (Angular 17) I used to extract colors with:
mat.get-color-from-palette($primary, 800). What would be the equivalent in Material 3 (Angular 18)?

You can use mat.get-theme-color for this.
Full Detailed Docs for get-theme-color
background-color: mat.get-theme-color($theme, primary, 50) !important;


We should also be aware of the number ranges for the hues, explained with examples below.
When dealing with M3 Palette's you can refer to this doc reference. Here notice how the palette is within the range of 0-100
$azure-palette: _apply-patches((
  0: #000000,
  10: #001b3f,
  20: #002f65,
  25: #003a7a,
  30: #00458f,
  35: #0050a5,
  40: #005cbb,
  50: #0074e9,
  60: #438fff,
  70: #7cabff,
  80: #abc7ff,
  90: #d7e3ff,
  95: #ecf0ff,
  98: #f9f9ff,
  99: #fdfbff,
  100: #ffffff,

If you are dealing with a M2 Palette ($pink-palette) you can refer this doc reference. Notice how the numbers range from 50-A700
$pink-palette: (
  50: #fce4ec,
  100: #f8bbd0,
  200: #f48fb1,
  300: #f06292,
  400: #ec407a,
  500: #e91e63,
  600: #d81b60,
  700: #c2185b,
  800: #ad1457,
  900: #880e4f,
  A100: #ff80ab,
  A200: #ff4081,
  A400: #f50057,
  A700: #c51162,
  contrast: (
    50: $dark-primary-text,
    100: $dark-primary-text,
    200: $dark-primary-text,
    300: $dark-primary-text,
    400: $dark-primary-text,
    500: $light-primary-text,
    600: $light-primary-text,
    700: $light-primary-text,
    800: $light-primary-text,
    900: $light-primary-text,
    A100: $dark-primary-text,
    A200: $light-primary-text,
    A400: $light-primary-text,
    A700: $light-primary-text,
  )
);

SCSS:
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

$theme: mat.define-theme(
  (
    color: (
      theme-type: light,
      primary: mat.$azure-palette,
      tertiary: mat.$blue-palette,
    ),
  )
);

body {
  background-color: mat.get-theme-color($theme, primary, 50) !important;
  @include mat.all-component-themes($theme);
  font-family: Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px;
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

@include mat.core();
@include mat.color-variants-backwards-compatibility($theme);

Stackblitz Demo

Thank you Naren. I wonder how a value of 800 is now 50. Where can I find a documentation that would help me?

@JohannesSchacht The m3 theme has the range 0-100 do check the color and select the appropriate hue you need.

Any idea how to get them when using system variables (css vars) instead ?

@Spock You mean --some-var: mat.get-theme-color($theme, primary, 50) !important;? could you explain the scenario, if possible on a question

@NarenMurali I am using Material3 and I don't think that mixin works there, sadly
